# How to deal with a change of marital status between application and interview for a US F-1 visa?

Tags: visas, usa, indian-citizens, f1-visas

I have prepared an application, which asks for marital status among many other information about me and my whereabouts.

I'm an Indian citizen applying for a US visa of type F-1.

As an applicant (i.e., now) I am single. However I will be attending the interview as a married man. I could take the easy way around by submitting this application after I got married. Unfortunately this application 'expires' before my marriage date.

I am not inclined toward generating a new application, thereby clogging up web space (though temporarily) and wasting my time.

Therefore I have a question:

Marital status as when is relevant? As on application date or appointment date?

Comment: Which country are you applying to? What's your citizenship? And what type of visa are you seeking? I don't think you need to worry about web space but depending on the specifics this could have ramifications for your visa.

Comment: All DS-160 forms can be filled with what your status will be on the date when you attend the interview. That said, this doesn't seem to be a direct travel question.

Comment: There is no issue - the application states what is your status _at the time of filling the application_ and not when your status will be when you go for an interview. So, simply tell the officer that since that time you have gotten married, and they can amend your application.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Are you marrying a US citizen? If not I doubt it will matter. Just update them when you get married or send them an email informing that you are getting married.

If you are marrying a US citizen then that can cause problems since part of the student F-1 visa is to prove your ties to India and that you plan to return there after your studies.